# How do I change the appearance of my web app on form submit?

Tags: html, forms, google-apps-script, web-applications

Ok so I have thee components, the script, the doget function, and the input html form.

the doget calls the form:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("inputHtml.html");

}
```

And the form on submit calls the test script

```
<input 
     type="button" 
     value="SPLIT gSheet" 
     onclick="google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(function(response){console.log(response);})
      .test(this.parentNode);" 
      style="background-color:#1a73e8;border-radius:10px;padding:5px;color: #fff; border-color: white;"
  />
```

and the code returns the response to the console log.

```
function test(e){

  var string = e.original + e.location + e.prefix;

var gDrive = e.original;
var filePrefix = e.prefix;
var destination = getIdFromUrl(e.location);
// do something with input
  return string;    

}//*****************************************************************************
```

My question itself is kind of basic, I'd be glad to be pointed at a good tutorial.

How do I have the script clear itself/call a new html page after it runs? Or while it is running? Ideally it would show a processing page when clicked and an output page when complete?

Comment: How about in the `withSuccessHandler()`; You could hide one div and display another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a form I use for uploading files:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <script>

  function fileUploadJs(frmData) 
  {
    document.getElementById('status').style.display ='inline';
    google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(updateOutput)
      .uploadTheFile(frmData)
  };
  function updateOutput(info) 
  {
    var br='<br />';
    var outputDiv = document.getElementById('status');
    outputDiv.innerHTML = br + 'File Upload Successful.' + br + 'File Name: ' + info.name + br + 'Content Type: ' + info.type + br + 'Folder Name: ' + info.folder;
  }
</script>
<style>
  body {background-color:#ffffff;}
  input{padding:2px;margin:2px;}
</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 id="main-heading">Main Heading</h1>
    <div id="formDiv">
      <form id="myForm">
        <input name="fileToLoad" type="file" /><br/>
        <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="fileUploadJs(this.parentNode)" />
      </form>
    </div>
  <div id="status" style="display: none">
  <!-- div will be filled with innerHTML after form submission. -->
  Uploading. Please wait...
  </div>  
  <div id="controls">
      <input type="button" value="Close" onClick="google.script.host.close();" />
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the gs:

```
function uploadTheFile(theForm) {
  var fileBlob=theForm.fileToLoad;
  var fldr = DriveApp.getFolderById(getGlobal('ExportsFolderId'));
  var file=fldr.createFile(fileBlob);
  var fi=formatFileName(file);
  var fileInfo={'name':fi.getName(),'type':fileBlob.getContentType(),'folder':fldr.getName()};
  return fileInfo;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This helps me to see multiple things that will allow me to expand my webapp from here (hiding showing areas, different ways the scripts can work, etc).